# How to automatically add and update the price total when adding an item with price

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, operator-keyword

I have been learning javascript, i'm on my second project called "expense tracker" i have been able to use DOM and functions but could not execute right on the operators.

I have 2 input text the first is "item name" and the second is "price".

I have 2 buttons first is "add" and 2nd is "deduct".

The problem is Im so confused to create functions on the operators that able to get the total price and auto update the total whenever I add items.

**I want to achieve:**

When ever I add Item the current total price will be updated automatically.
When ever I deduct item the current total price will be updated automatically.

This the Javascript. I can able add and append items and price but dont know how to add and deduct with automatic price total.

```
    const itemname = document.querySelector('#itemname');
    const price = document.querySelector('#price');
    
    
    //set requirements and limitations
    const isRequired = value => value === '' ? false : true;
    
    //set error trapping and message
    
    const showError = (input, message) => {
        const formgroup = input.parentElement;
    
        formgroup.classList.remove('success');  
        formgroup.classList.add('error');
    
        const error = formgroup.querySelector('small');
        error.textContent = message;
    }
    const showSuccess = (input, message) => {
        const formgroup = input.parentElement;
    
        formgroup.classList.remove('error');
        formgroup.classList.add('success');
    
        const error = formgroup.querySelector('small');
        error.textContent = message;
    }
    
    // Verifying fields if correct
    const checkItemname = () =>{
    let valid = false;
    const itemnameTrim = itemname.value.trim();
    const priceTrim = price.value.trim();
    
        if(!isRequired(itemnameTrim)){
            showError(itemname, "Pls type item name!");
        }
        else if(!isRequired(priceTrim)){
            showError(price, "Pls type price!");
        }
        else{
            showSuccess(itemname);
            showSuccess(price);
            addItem();
            valid = true;
        }
        return valid;
    }
    
    const addItem = () => {
        const itemnameTrim = itemname.value.trim();
    
        const tableRowItem = document.createElement("tr");
        const tableDataItem = document.createElement("td");
        const tableTxtnode = document.createTextNode(itemnameTrim);
    
        tableRowItem.appendChild(tableDataItem);
        tableDataItem.appendChild(tableTxtnode);
        document.getElementById("td-item").appendChild(tableRowItem);
    
        const priceTrim = price.value.trim();
    
        const tableDataPrice = document.createElement("td");
        const tableTxtnodePrice = document.createTextNode(priceTrim);
    
        tableRowItem.appendChild(tableDataPrice);
        tableDataPrice.appendChild(tableTxtnodePrice);
        
        document.getElementById("itemname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("price").value = "";
    }

//Deduct button
const deductItem = () => {
    const itemnameTrim = itemname.value.trim();

    const tableRowItem = document.createElement("tr");
    const tableDataItem = document.createElement("td");
    const tableTxtnode = document.createTextNode(itemnameTrim);

    tableRowItem.className = 'redtext';
    console.log(tableRowItem);

    tableRowItem.appendChild(tableDataItem);
    tableDataItem.appendChild(tableTxtnode);
    document.getElementById("td-item").appendChild(tableRowItem);


    const priceTrim = price.value.trim();

    const tableDataPrice = document.createElement("td");
    const tableTxtnodePrice = document.createTextNode(priceTrim);

    tableRowItem.appendChild(tableDataPrice);
    tableDataPrice.appendChild(tableTxtnodePrice);
    
    document.getElementById("itemname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("price").value = "";
}


//Call the buttons and evoke functions
const deductBtn = document.querySelector('#deductBtn')
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#addBtn')

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    checkItemname()});

deductBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    deductItem()});
```

Comment: Would you post what you have tried, including HTML and javascript?

Comment: It is hard to imagine what exactly do you want. It would be great if you could add some code and add what you are expecting, If you add some code then more people will happy  to help. 

Comment: Hi added the javascript code

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```